Diskcryptor didn't install well: "error occurred while installing driver error code 2". Now it cannot boot. How can I fix it?
I started my computer and wanted to use DiskCryptor (it worked perfectly on my computer a few weeks ago). However it recently froze each time I started it.
I then reinstalled it. Yet, when I did it it told me "error occurred while installing driver error code 2".
I nonetheless pursued the installation.
However each time when I launch it it tells me "You must restart your computer before the new settings take effect".
But when I restart the computer nothing changes (it always ask me to restart).
How can I solve this issue?

@DrMoishePippik I don't understand your comment. My problem is to make the software DiskCryptor work.

It appears that multiple attempts to use that disk encryption tool has caused issues, possibly losing necessary operating system information. If you cannot boot the PC any longer, the safest option is to restore the whole drive from the last disk image. Once it is working, you can decide whether to try that encryption software, or not.

@DrMoishePippik the thing is that this is obly the software that causes issues not the ssd. On another computer with diskcryptor I have 0 problem to uncrypt the ssd. Hence Im trying to understand how to fix the software.
